# how set animation end listener for AnimatorSet

Tags: java, android

we want set end listener in below method:

```
 private void animation1() {
        ObjectAnimator scaleXAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mLogo, "scaleX", 5.0F, 1.0F);
        scaleXAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        scaleXAnimation.setDuration(1200);
        ObjectAnimator scaleYAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mLogo, "scaleY", 5.0F, 1.0F);
        scaleYAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        scaleYAnimation.setDuration(1200);
        ObjectAnimator alphaAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mLogo, "alpha", 0.0F, 1.0F);
        alphaAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        alphaAnimation.setDuration(1200);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.play(scaleXAnimation).with(scaleYAnimation).with(alphaAnimation);
        animatorSet.setStartDelay(500);
        animatorSet.start();
    }
```

how can we do something after this animation be end?

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
    animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        }
    });
```